# Spring-RMI event causes java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED

Tags: java, spring, java-8

**The problem**

Problem with Spring 4.3.3 and Java 8 when project uses RMI. Application throws exception during using RMI to send event to other application. It was working fine (application is few years old) but it broke after some patch installation on Weblogic server.

**The code**

The application uses spring-context

```
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext

 private void publishEvent(final ApplicationEvent event) {
        taskExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                publisher.publishEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }
```

**The logs**

```
> 2019-10-01 10:42:14,366 ERROR .c.b.i.i.ImportServiceImpl - An unexpected error occurred during the synchronous import process.
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
        java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:215)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.getStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:237)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.invoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:258)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

(...)       


>   Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
        java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:125)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:200)
        ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.filterCheck(ObjectInputStream.java:1255)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1878)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:123)
        ... 106 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like you have to whitelist some class for deserialisation. Check the release notes of your Weblogic server to see if it mentions serialization somewhere.

Comment: But the final ApplicationEvent event which is sent through RMI is serializable and has serialization uid. It should be serialized and deserialized to be sent by first application and received by other application. You mean I should whitelist this class for deserialization on the receiver side ?

Comment: It looks like a newer version of Weblogic uses [serialization filters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputFilter.html). It doesn't matter that the class is Serializable, or anything. This class is filtered. And you need to whitelist it. I have no idea how Weblogic works, I just know which java facility was used to get such an error trace.

Comment: Note that while `java.io.ObjectInputFilter` has been added in Java 9, the functionality existed already in Java 8, buried in `sun.misc.ObjectInputFilter`.

Comment: I added this class to whitelist but it didn't help Dweblogic.oif.serialFilter="mypackage.ApplicationEvent". Logs shows <Oct 2, 2019 11:49:03 AM CEST> <Info> <java.io.serialization> <BEA-000000> <ObjectInputFilter REJECTED: class java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler, array length: -1, nRefs: 7, depth: 2, bytes What helped was setting Dweblogic.oif.serialFilter="*" But I am not sure if it is correct. I could add RemoteObjectInvocationHandler to the filter if this is correct way, but it is not my class it is jdk class.

Comment: Just received instructions from weblogic :) JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterScope=weblogic

Comment: @stephanmathew: As you solved your question, why not self-answer it? :) This comment is rather hidden

Answer (score 3):

I used the solution proposed above in a similiar situation and it works for me:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterScope=weblogic
```

You can find the description of the Weblogic settings [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SECMG/conf-security-for-domain.htm#SECMG-GUID-902F255F-7325-4F48-A127-57F9851B5330).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation when migrating from weblogic 12.1.3.0 to weblogic 12.2.1.4.
Ultimately I debugged the weblogic server into java.io.ObjectInputStream#filterCheck, in debug I could see the filter being used.

Very strangely weblogic 12.2.1.4 comes with a preset filter that does not allow for java.rmi.server.* classes to be serialized .

Therefore the fix that worked for me was to add the whole package to the allowed filter:

```
java.rmi.server.*
```

Oracle documentation explains that the default behaviour will be "combine" what we define will take precedence over the predefined filter.

(windows)

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilter=java.rmi.server.* %JAVA_OPTIONS%
```

(*nix)

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.oif.serialFilter=java.rmi.server.* $JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

I did see the same thing not with the spring framework but with deploying servlet based rmi in WebLogic.

I did the code change

`import java.rmi.server.*;`

and added the system property

```
 -Dweblogic.oif.serialFilterScope=weblogic
```

this worked.