# spring-boot-maven-plugin: start does not recognize that app has already started

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, rmi, jmx

I'm trying to use the **spring-boot-maven-plugin** for integration tests like documented, but I always get 'Spring application did not start before the configured timeout'. However, using 'fork=false' spring server app is saying:

```
18:30:14.442 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
18:30:14.446 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - Completed initialization in 4 ms
18:30:21.918 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
18:31:05.899 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

Because of this, I guess that the plugin simply has not found out that the app already has started.

However, it I use 'fork=true' (default), I always get the following error:

```
16:40:54.546 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectorServerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/demo/app2/config/ConfigureRMI.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:9001/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springdoc.demo.app2.Application.main(Application.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:9001/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:854)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:501)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConnectorServerFactoryBean.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: null
    at jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:162)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:230)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:417)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:713)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:496)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:391)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:375)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:73)
    at jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:156)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:91)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:468)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:298)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.filterCheck(ObjectInputStream.java:1287)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1772)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:88)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

These are my questions:

- How does the plugin try to find out if the application has started?

  - If 'fork=true'? JMX/RMI? Which port? Which MBean?
  - If 'fork=false'?
- How to avoid the error in case of 'fork=true'?

Comment: Perhaps my question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198247/rmi-event-causes-java-io-invalidclassexception-filter-status-rejected but this is also not answered.